# Process for one user starting a form and another finishing it

Tags: python, web, flask

I'm using Flask/Python for what it matters.

I need to have one user begin filling out a form, lets say question 1 and 2, and then save that form and send it via email to another user to finish the form, question 3. The second user then saves it again and the final product is stored.

Question 1 would be a name field and question 2 would be a status field (like here, not going, etc) and question 3, the question for the second user, would be a 'yes' 'no' to confirm the information from the first user.

That description was just to outline the full workflow. If anyone can point me to some useful information and/or examples how of how to send the uncompleted form for another use to finish I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define one model which contain three fields and define two forms. The first form contain question1 and question2. The second form inherit from the first form and add question3.

There are some views:

- a view to show the first form to the first user to fill in
- a view to save the first form data to the database(SQLALchemy) and send email to the second user that contain a url(with a id point to the data object) which map to the next view
- a view which accept the id of data object and show the second form to the second user, in this view you can create the second form with `form = Form2(obj=Data.query.get(id))` to populate data from data object
- a view to save the second from data to the database(You only define one model and update the last field in this view function)